# Play framework - Cross fields Read

Tags: json, parsing, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to read a field based on different field?

This is the case class:

```
case class Person(children: List[String], hasChildren: Boolean)
```

I want to fill hasChildren based on the children list.

So I tried the following reads:

```
implicit val personReads: Reads[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "children").readNullable[List[String]].map(_.getOrElse(List())) and
  (JsPath \ "hasChildren").read[Boolean](
    (JsPath \ "children").readNullable[List[String]].map{
      case Some(opt) => opt.nonEmpty
      case None => false
    }))
```

But although I provide children it matches the None case, and return false.

What am I doing wrong? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. You are thinking in the right direction (using `map`). Your reader must be

```
(
  (__ \ "children").readNullable[List[String]].map(_.getOrElse(List())) and
  (__ \ "children").readNullable[List[String]].map(_.exists(_.nonEmpty))  
  )(Person.apply _)
```

You must implement reader with properties order and types like your case class. Names of properties used in path are not important.

**Important:** `readNullable[T]` search optional or nullable field at JsPath (field not found or null is None).